# Hooking up events to NSWindowController in single window application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I've been working with the iPhone/iPad for a while using Xcode and have no trouble hooking up all the required connections to a `UIViewController` in interface builder to make things work, however this seems much more difficult when attempting a simple app for OSX.

I've created a new Cocoa application in Xcode (non-document based) with a main NIB file for the window.
I have created a new `NSWindowController` subclass called `TestWindowController`.
In IB, I change the file's owner to my new `TestWindowController`.
I've added some `IBAction`'s to the controller subclass and hooked them up in IB.

All appears fine and compiles but when I look at the debug log I see:

Could not connect the action sayHelloClicked: to target of class TestWindowController.

I've been going round in circles for hours trying various methods and I just can't get the actions hooked up. Where am I going wrong?

I should also mention that I tried ditching the view controller all together and adding the actions to the main `NSApplicationDelegate` class with the same results.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Please post the code were you instantiate an object of type `TestWindowController` and load the corresponding nib file.

Comment: @Bavarious OP said that he set the File's Owner to `TestWindowController`.

Comment: @Richard Yup, and File’s Owner must be instantiated before the nib file is loaded, hence my request.